# Submit form stored in one plugin from another plugin?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, wp-remote-request

I have two plugins `pluginA` and `pluginB`. `PluginA` contains a form with a single button which when pressed will do some calculations.
`PluginA` works fine, however, I want to be able to submit this form remotely from different plugin within the same website (both plugins are resided in same website)
I did some investigation and found `wp_remote_request` can make remote request. I tried to use it with basic `url` to plugin page that contains form but it returns content to login. Apparently it needs to contain login credentials within request header.

Any idea how can I achieve remote form submission?

**CODE**

```
$url = site_url('wp-admin/tools.php?page=dt_documents_tagging_menu&remotely_sumbitted=true');
$args = array( 'method'=>'GET' );
$result = wp_remote_request( $url, $args );
```

`$result` when print_r return login form

Comment: How about attempting to login via GET when retrieving the URL?
The following post should help you: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/32209/login-to-wordpress-with-get-variables-instead-of-post

Comment: Thanks TomC.. Your link helped me to some extent in what I was looking for.. Cheers

Comment: Glad to hear it - please consider giving it a bump up then and also post your answer for others. Thanks